# При клике по label не устанавливается checked

Tags: javascript, html

Добавил кнопку "выбрать всё":

```
<div class="width_3proc">
    <label class="padding_5px" titte="Выбрать все">
        <input type="checkbox" class="check_all-464" name="check_all" check-all="464">
    </label>
</div>
```

Повесил событие:

```
$('input[name="check_all"]').on('click',function(){
    id=$(this).attr('check-all');
    let ch=$(this).prop('checked');
    ic=$('#project-'+id+' input.bron');
    for (let i=0;i<ic.length;i++){$(ic[i]).prop('checked',ch);}
});
```

Но теперь отвалился label. при клике не устанавливается checked в input:

```
<div id="bron-1408" class="brons color-status-2" data-brone="1408">
    <div class="width_73proc tool-1408">
        <label class="tool_name padding_5px" for="bron-1408">ЛОР-комбайн Medstar UE-3000 базовая версия</label>
    </div>
    <div class="width_24proc tool-1408 status-2">
        <label class="status_name padding_5px" for="bron-1408">Авторизовано</label>
    </div>
    <div class="width_3proc tool-1408 status-2">
        <label class="padding_5px">
            <input type="checkbox" id="bron-1408" class="bron-1408" name="bron-1408" check-brone="1408">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Почему?

Comment: Что, собственно, изменилось оттого, что Вы поменяли "1417" на "1408"? Атрибут `check-all="464"` все равно показывает неизвестно куда, а слова `project` ни в каких `id` нет.

Comment: @Igor Вы были абсолютно правы. Я просто уже не стал выкладывать верный код)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Напутано с `for`, `id` и т.п. Отваливание `label`-а со скриптом никак не связано.

```js
$('input[name="check_all"]').on('click', function() {
  let id = $(this).attr('check-all');
  let ch = $(this).prop('checked');
  $('#project-' + id + ' input.bron').each(function(){ $(this).prop('checked', ch); });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="width_3proc">
  <label class="padding_5px" titte="Выбрать все">
    <input type="checkbox" class="check_all-464" name="check_all" check-all="1417">Выбрать все
  </label>
</div>

<br/><br/>

<div id="project-1417" class="brons color-status-2" data-brone="1417">

  <div class="width_73proc tool-1417">
    <label class="tool_name padding_5px" for="check_bron-1417">Dr. Camscope DCS-103R видеоректоскоп</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="width_24proc tool-1417 status-2">
    <label class="status_name padding_5px" for="check_bron-1417">Авторизовано</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="width_3proc tool-1417 status-2">
    <label class="padding_5px">
      <input type="checkbox" id="check_bron-1417" class="bron" name="bron" check-brone="1417">
    </label>
  </div>
  
</div>
```