# Как отмечать определенные checkbox при клике по ссылке?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброе время суток,
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно отмечать checkbox, с определенным значением id при клике по ссылке c таким же значением data атрибута?
Пример:

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="continent-1">Африка</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="continent-2">Азия</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="continent-3">Европа</a>
...
<input type="checkbox" id="continent-1">
<input type="checkbox" id="continent-2">
<input type="checkbox" id="continent-3">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("a[data-id]").click(function(e){
  var $check = $("#" + $(this).data("id"));
  $check.prop("checked", !$check.prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="continent-1">Африка</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="continent-2">Азия</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="continent-3">Европа</a>
...
<input type="checkbox" id="continent-1">
<input type="checkbox" id="continent-2">
<input type="checkbox" id="continent-3">
```

Не лучше ли использовать для этого `label` с атрибутом `for`?

Comment: label - это первое что я попробовал) К сожалению, если можно было, так бы и сделал. У меня карта SVG, надо кликабельными континенты сделать, label там не захотел работать, только ссылки.
Спасибо за код, все работает как надо)

Comment: @OlegLantukh Пожалуйста. Успехов!

Answer (score 2):

Подобных вопросов тут задано масса. Например [мой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/899494/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-label-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-checked). Тут вообще не нужен `JS`. Просто необходимо добавить стилизацию через `CSS`. И всё работает без тега `<a>`.

> P.S. Лучше выглядит с отключенным выделением.

```css
.ml{
 color:darkblue;
 user-select: none;
}
.ml:hover{
 color:blue;
}
```

```html
<label class="ml" for="Africa"> Африка </label>
<label class="ml" for="Asia"> Азия </label>
<label class="ml" for="Europe"> Европа </label>

<input type="checkbox" id="Africa">
<input type="checkbox" id="Asia">
<input type="checkbox" id="Europe">
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, в моем случаи label не подходит, мне карту надо прикрутить на фильтр) в общем все сложно)
Решение уже нашел, но все равно спасибо!